# Add column to ensure composite key is unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, composite-primary-key

I have a table which needs to have a composite primary key based on 2 columns (`Material number, Plant`).

For example, this is how it is currently (note that these rows are not unique):

```
MATERIAL_NUMBER    PLANT NUMBER
------------------ ----- ------
000000000000500672 G072  1
000000000000500672 G072  1
000000000000500672 G087  1
000000000000500672 G207  1
000000000000500672 G207  1
```

However, I'll need to add the additional column (`NUMBER`) to the composite key such that each row is unique, and it must work like this:

For each `MATERIAL_NUMBER`, for each `PLANT`, let `NUMBER` start at 1 and increment by 1 for each duplicate record.

This would be the desired output:

```
MATERIAL_NUMBER    PLANT NUMBER
------------------ ----- ------
000000000000500672 G072  1
000000000000500672 G072  2
000000000000500672 G087  1
000000000000500672 G207  1
000000000000500672 G207  2
```

How would I go about achieving this, specifically in SQL Server?

Best Regards!

Comment: Using a window function? `ROW_NUMBER()`. But why you need to do so? Why don't just add an `IDENTITY()` column and make it the PK of the table?

Comment: If `MATERIAL_NUMBER` and `PLANT` are meant to be a composite key, how are you ending up with duplicates in the first place?

Comment: There are ways to achieve what you want e.g. with triggers, scanning the table for max NUMBER but unless carefully setup, you can get race conditions. The question is why not use IDENTITY as @Sami suggests.

Comment: Solved, thank you @Sami. (In short, I would add an identity column - but this table sits in a database underlying a SAP system - so they are very particular about the formats....)

Comment: If it gets this messy - maybe a surrogate `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` would be the simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

See below:

```
SELECT MATERIAL_NUMBER, PLANT, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MATERIAL_NUMBER, PLANT ORDER BY VALID_FROM)) as NUMBER
FROM Table_Name
```

Will output the table in question, with the NUMBER column properly defined

Comment: Wait, if you have a `VALID_FROM` column (which you failed to tell us about), and appears to be unique by your definition above (for a combination of `MATERIAL_NUMBER` and `PLANT` at least), why not use that in your key definition..?

Comment: @Larnu that would be correct - however (as comment above), this table underlies a SAP S4/HANA system, and they specify the format...

Comment: Be careful with this, though -- if any row ever gets deleted, or new rows inserted "in between", the numbers will get "shuffled around". The IDs produced these way are unique *per result set*, not persistently so.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is actual table,

```
create table #temp1(MATERIAL_NUMBER varchar(30),PLANT varchar(30), NUMBER int)
```

Suppose you want to insert only single record then,

```
declare @Num int
select @Num=isnull(max(number),0) from #temp1 where MATERIAL_NUMBER='000000000000500672' and PLANT='G072'

insert into #temp1 (MATERIAL_NUMBER,PLANT , NUMBER )
values ('000000000000500672','G072',@Num+1)
```

Suppose you want to insert bulk record.Your bulk record sample data is like

```
create table #temp11(MATERIAL_NUMBER varchar(30),PLANT varchar(30))
insert into #temp11 (MATERIAL_NUMBER,PLANT)values
 ('000000000000500672','G072')
,('000000000000500672','G072')
,('000000000000500672','G087')
,('000000000000500672','G207')
,('000000000000500672','G207')

You want to insert `#temp11` in `#temp1` maintaining number id

insert into #temp1 (MATERIAL_NUMBER,PLANT , NUMBER )
select t11.MATERIAL_NUMBER,t11.PLANT 
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by t11.MATERIAL_NUMBER,t11.PLANT order by (select null))+isnull(maxnum,0) as Number from #temp11 t11
outer apply(select MATERIAL_NUMBER,PLANT,max(NUMBER)maxnum from #temp1 t  where t.MATERIAL_NUMBER=t11.MATERIAL_NUMBER  
and t.PLANT=t11.PLANT group by MATERIAL_NUMBER,PLANT) t

select * from #temp1
drop table #temp1
drop table #temp11
```

Main question is Why you need number column ? In mot of the cases you don't need number column,you can use `ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by t11.MATERIAL_NUMBER,t11.PLANT order by (select null))` to display where you need. This will be more efficient.

Or tell the actual situation and number of rows involved where you will be needing `Number` column.